# Bootstrap Collapsing Table Rows

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking recommendations for something similar to a table of four columns that would collapse into a dropdown on mobile devices.  My original code is a bootstrap table but the table at it's smallest size is still too big for mobile devices.  I'm thinking I could collapse into a drop down because really all that needs to be seen on mobile devices is the first row which contains a clickable link to an expanded detail view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach may be to use two different controls - a table for bigger screens and a dropdown for smaller screens - and include both in your page.

Then hide the control that is not required based on the screen size. Since you're using Bootstrap already, look into its [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities). You will find predefined CSS classes like `.hidden-sm` or `.hidden-lg` that help you with that.